# Tricky "make" target requirements

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a situation where I need to compile some source files from a library into my own program.  The directories the source files are in are not writeable by me.  Instead I have a local "build" directory where all the work is done.

The problem I am having the the translation of the paths.  The source files are named, say `xxxx.cpp` and `yyyy.cpp`, and they are in `/path/to/source/xxxx/xxxx.cpp` and `/path/to/source/yyyy/yyyy.cpp`.

Using $(patsubst ...) I can happily convert those paths to `build/xxxx/xxxx.cpp` etc, but I can't get it to strip the first `xxxx` off.

I could do with crafting a target that would match something like this:

```
build/%.o: /path/to/source/%/%.cpp
        $(CXX) ...
```

...but I can't get that to work at all.  I guess it doesn't like the double wildcard in the latter part of the target.

The "source" for the names is a single variable with just the "xxxx" and "yyyy" in:

```
SYS_LIBS = xxxx yyyy
```

Any suggestions on how to get something like this to work?

Oh, I need it to be a "generic" solution - this will be an included makefile in many projects that use this library of files, so hand-crafting a target per file is not an option.  I cannot predict what files will be in the library.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use [vpath](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-2-SECT-3) to let make find the files itself. You just define

```
vpath %.cpp /path/to/source
vpath %.cpp /path/to/source2
vpath %.cpp /path/to/source3

build/%.o : %.cpp
   $(CXX)
```

You can define more than one path to source that way, but be careful if you have the same file in more than one folder (e.g. a.cpp in both path_to_source1 and path_to_source2)

Comment: What about if you want `vpath %.cpp /path/to/source/*` for example?

Comment: You can have more than one vpath, as I changed it. AFAIK, you can't use wildcards however. Usually, you don't have that many folders holding source so it's not really a problem (if it is, you can solve it with generated stuff, but it's usually too painful)

Comment: I cannot predict what the last part of the path will be - as I mentioned in my question.  It all depends on what libraries the end user has installed on their system.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use `vpath`, as Bruce suggests. If there are many directories under `/path/to/source/` you can use

```
SRCS = $(wildcard /path/to/source/*)
vpath %.cpp $(SRCS)
```

(This works as long as the directories go only one level down from there. If there are things like `/path/to/source/foo/bar/zzzz/zzzz.cpp`, then you'll have to fall back on something like `find`.)

If you really want to do path translation, this will do it:

```
X := $(patsubst %.cpp,build/%.o,$(notdir $(X)))
```

Or (I don't know why you'd want to do it this way, but you could):

```
X := $(shell echo $(X) | sed 's|.*/\(.*\)\.cpp|build/\1\.o|')
```